# -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections in keil

Tags: stm32, keil

How can I set  "-ffunction-sections" and "-fdata-sections" flag in KEIL?

I can set these two flags in sw4stm32.

Is there any similar flags in Keil compiler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use the linker parameters from the **Misc Controls** tab which is under Linker tab and the linker parameters should shown in the **Linker Control String**.